# Get min and max from data field to use in domain scale

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega

I have a Vega chart for which I need to compute dynamically the x axis domain. Reading the documentation, I see that I might have 2 options:

- Data transform aggregate min and max
- Data transform extent

My data transform aggregate min max implementation is as follows:

```
 {
   'name': 'minMaxSales',
   'source': 'monthlySales',
   'transform': { 'type': 'aggregate', 'fields': ['datum.sales_total', 'datum.sales_total'], 'ops': ['min', 'max'], 'as': ['minSales', 'maxSales'] }
 }
```

X scale defintion:

```
'scales': [
      {
        'name': 'x',
        'type': 'linear',
        'round': false,
        'nice': false,
        'zero': true,
        'domain': {
          'data': 'minMaxSales'
        },
        'range': 'width'
      }
]
```

My data transform extent solution code is as follows:

```
{
        'name': 'minMaxSales',
        'source': 'monthlySales',
        'transform': { 'type': 'extent', 'field': 'datum.sales_total', 'signal': 'extent' }
}
```

Same code for the X scale definition.

In both cases I get the following error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:1832 TypeError: data.transform.forEach is not a function
at parseData (data.js:11)
......
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform` should be an array of objects ([see here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/)). All you need to do is add square brackets (`[]`) around `{ 'type': 'aggregate', 'fields': ['datum.sales_total', 'datum.sales_total'], 'ops': ['min', 'max'], 'as': ['minSales', 'maxSales'] }` and it should work properly.

Comment: I have this exact same syntax. But maybe I'm not passing the aggregate correctly to the domain?